# some planes' texture are not rendered properly

Tags: rendering, texturing

this is a rendered image (with F12) of my work.

[image: a busy cat]

It's very basic: a plane subdivided several times and "distorted" to look like a terrain with a material and a texture. Why some squares of the terrain are gray?

Comment: Please provide us with a screenshot of your material setup for textures and material based questions.
Note: I noticed you didn't apply any smooth shading on the model. this might be something you want to do.
https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/meshes/editing/smoothing.html

Comment: Welcome to Blender.SE. What render engine do you use? If BI, try in Edit mode selecting all the mesh and unwrapping once more (if e.g. you created those faces after unwrapping). In BI or Cycles check whether those faces belong to the same material.

Comment: @Mr Zak I use Blender render, in Cycles it doesn't render textures at all. However i solved the problem by raising the terrain a little bit. Not sure about the cause, thank you

Comment: Probably it means that there was another object interfering with this one. Cycles won't show textures out of the box because Cycles and BI materials aren't interchangeable; you should provide Cycles with Texture Coordinates to make image texture render (either Object / Generated or UV if UV map is present). Glad it appeared to be solved.